# Jquery hide dropdown list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a small question.

I have 2 select form , and i want when i choose rental the employed type become hidden and here's my code :

```
<label>Type</label>
 <select id="Type-option" class="form-control">
     <option value="employed">Employed</option>
     <option value="rental">Rental</option>
</select>

<label>Employed Type</label>
<select id="employedType-option" value="employedType-option" class="form-control">
     <option value="fulltime">FULLTIME</option>
     <option value="parttime">PARTTIME</option>
</select>

$(function() {
 var select = $('#Type-option');
select.on('change', function() {
  if (select.val() == "rental") {
    $('#employedType-option').hide();
  } else {
    $('#employedType-option').show();
  }
 });
});
```

any idea ?

Comment: It is working properly. I don't get any issue.
Check this- https://jsfiddle.net/4vopp97z/

Comment: What's the error? I got your code running here: https://jsfiddle.net/p2tz02qf/

Comment: @hi, its not working here in my local.
nothing error. any idea ?

Comment: ur above code is working, check properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions here
1. Never mix your mark up with your javascript.Consider binding events at javascript
2. I have modified your markup a bit,because when you hide employeetype u need to hide the label too

check the following snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var select = $('#Type-option');
  var employeeTypeOption=$('#employedType-option');
  var employedType=$('#employedType');
   select.on('change', function() {
    var selectOption=select.find('option:selected').val();
  if (selectOption == "rental") {
   employeeTypeOption.hide();
  employedType.hide();
  } else {
    employeeTypeOption.show();
    employedType.show();
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Type</label>
 <select id="Type-option" class="form-control">
     <option value="employed">Employed</option>
     <option value="rental">Rental</option>
</select>

<span id="employedType">
<label>Employed Type</label>
<select id="employedType-option" value="employedType-option" class="form-control">
     <option value="fulltime">FULLTIME</option>
     <option value="parttime">PARTTIME</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: cool...If it is of any help,please consider accepting answer :)

Comment: why I add condition like this, not working.
else  if (select.val() == "employed" || "parttime"){
    $('#employedType-option').show();
    $('#employedType').show();
    $('#basic-salary').hide();
    $('#hourly-rate').show();

Comment: why I add condition like this, not working.

    else  if (select.val() == "employed" || "parttime"){
    $('#employedType-option').show();
    $('#employedType').show();
    $('#basic-salary').hide();
    $('#hourly-rate').show();

Comment: parttime is of employedType-option box.you cannot check it on select.val() .change the if condition to ( selectOption=="employed") ||  $("#employedType-option option:selected").val()=="parttime") .but a question here ,by default employed dropdown would be visible. When it is hidden by previous if condition how can check if it is parttime or not

Comment: the issue is to long too explain it in here. can we have a small chit chat ?

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax.
check `$(document).on.('action','selection',function(){});` signature.

Tyr with below code

```
 $(document).on('change','#Type-option', function() {
 if ($(this).val() == "rental") {
    $('#employedType-option').hide();
 } else {
    $('#employedType-option').show();
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i guess you have missed one of these otherwise your code is working fine

- Add reference to `jquery library`
- Wrap your jquery code inside `script` tag.

  ```
  <script>
   $(function() {
   var select = $('#Type-option');    select.on('change', function() {
   if (select.val() == "rental") {
     $('#employedType-option').hide();
   } 
   else {
     $('#employedType-option').show();
   }
    });    
  });

  </script>
  ```

Comment: it's inside script Wrap. and I've added bootstrap jquery.

Comment: See your console you must be getting `$ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. try the working demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<label>Type</label>
 <select id="Type-option" class="form-control">
     <option value="employed">Employed</option>
     <option value="rental">Rental</option>
</select>


<label id="emp">Employed Type</label>
<select id="employedType-option" value="employedType-option" class="form-control">
  <option value="fulltime">FULLTIME</option>
  <option value="parttime">PARTTIME</option>
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $("#Type-option").on('change',function(){
  var theVal = $(this).val();//get the selected value

  if(theVal == "rental"){
   $("#emp").hide();
   $("#employedType-option").hide()
  }
  else{
   $("#emp").show();
   $("#employedType-option").show()
  }

 })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```